# How can I reorder specific columns based on their date values?

Tags: r, sorting

I have a script which produces a .csv output like this:

[image]

However, there is a problem which I have highlighted: the date-named columns aren't always in the correct order.

I have tried to sort the columns by name, but this affects the first three columns (`retailer`, `department`, `type`) which have to always be in those first three columns.  This happens because they are ordered by date first, then by character values.

How can I reorder the columns so that the first three columns remain where they are and also get the dates in the correct order?

**UPDATE:**

I can order the columns like this, which is the first part of the solution:

```
sort(names(output))
```

In this format, I now need to move the final three columns to the beginning (this will always be the same for every data frame that is generated so will be fine).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi! Have you tried sorting only from the 4th column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to convert to `Date` class and then order it

```
# using a pattern, get the column index
i1 <- grep("^\\d{2}", names(df1))
# sort the extracted the column names after converting to 'Date' class
nm1 <-  names(df1)[i1][order(as.Date(names(df1)[i1], '%d/%m/%Y'))]
# get the names of the other columns
nm2 <- setdiff(names(df1), names(df1)[i1])
# concatenate the columns
df2 <- df1[c(nm2, nm1)]
df2
#    retailer department      type 22/03/2015 15/01/2017 25/07/2018 11/01/2019 12/01/2019
#1        1          a completed          4          1          2          4          1
#2        2          b completed          1          1          2          3          4
#3        3          c completed          5          1          2          2          3
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(retailer = 1:3, department = letters[1:3], 
 type = 'completed', `11/01/2019` = c(4, 3, 2),
 `12/01/2019` = c(1, 4, 3), `15/01/2017` = 1,
 `25/07/2018` = 2, `22/03/2015` = c(4, 1, 5), check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: This makes sense but it isn't working; the columns are still in the same (incorrect) order and it now produces duplicate columns (i.e. `2019-01-12.1`) in addition to the existing columns. (I can't share my script either as it is over 200 lines long.)

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. Can you check the output of 'nm1' and 'nm2'.  I think there must be some simple mistake that causes the issue.  Are you sure that the column names are unique

Comment: I have checked and both `nm1` and `nm2` share the same date values and `x` value also; however, `nm2` also has `retailer`, `department` and `type` whereas `nm1` doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. The 'nm2' had a mistake.  Now check it

Comment: It should work now as the 'nm2' was created by taking the setdiff of setdiff which created the duplication of columns

Comment: Yes, this has resolved the duplication issue but the columns still aren't in order. Given your sample data and solution it clearly works, so I will accept on those grounds; the issue must be elsewhere at my end. I should also mention that my final data frame (`output`) is composed of two other data frames that are iterated through a list of retailers. I am unsure if that might make a difference, but it's all I can think of that could be causing this; however, when I apply your solution to my final `output` data frame it doesn't reorder the columns.

Comment: I should also mention that `nm1` contains `x` and then all of the date values (in the same, unsorted order) and `nm2` contains `x`, `retailer`, `department` and `type`.  Is that what you expected them to contain?

Comment: I have a partial solution to order the columns correctly, but I can't move the last three columns to the beginning. This correctly orders the columns by name: `sort(names(output))`.How can I now move the last three columns to the beginning (this will always be the case)?

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. With the pattern, `nm1` should have only the date columns.  Can you check whether you have other columns that start with numbers and not 'date'.  If you know the last three columns, `nm3 <- tail(names(df1), 3); df1[c(nm3, setdiff(c(nm1, nm2), nm3))]`

Comment: I've been debugging this for a couple of hours now and I have no idea why it doesn't work within the function; however, I did manage to find a solution which was to wrap the `nm2` generation in `sort` (`nm2 <- sort(names(output)[i1][order(as.Date(names(output)[i1], '%d/%m/%Y'))])`).  This gives me the desired outcome, despite the version without the `sort` having worked in standalone tests. This is now resolved, but I am very curious / baffled as to why this wouldn't work in my function without using `sort`. Either way, thank you for your help with this.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. It is a bit strange too considering the fact that I tried with a reproducible example.  Do you have any Dates in multiple formats

Comment: No, all dates are in `Date` format - I explicitly convert the dates in the raw data early on in the script (`data$date <- as.Date(data$date)`).

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. Withotu a reproducible example, it is bit difficult to debug the issue

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that. I will continue to look into it as I am sure that the problem will become apparent soon enough. I initially thought that it could be because I am calling the script via `Rscript ...` on the command line but whilst testing in RStudio the columns still weren't sorted unless I added `sort` first of all.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. Can you just get the `dput(names(data))` because there will be simple issues that cause this

Comment: Here you go - `c("retailer", "department", "type", "date", "count")`.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. But, these doesn't include the `date` format dates.  I would need that to understand what is going on.  If it is really big, then do a subset of data and apply the same code, check if that still gives you the issue.  If that is the case, just copy/paste the `names` of that data as dput.  I would start debugging in that way

Comment: The dates are converted once these data have been read into R. The way the data come in is from a SQL query via BigQuery from a Python script and that is then brought into R. I tried using the `bigrquery` package but there is no option to select the BigQuery server that I need, so had to use Python/pandas instead. I can `dput` the first 200 rows of the dataset (excluding `retailer` and `department` for confidentiality reasons) if that helps. If so, I will add it to my question.

Comment: @MusTheDataGuy. When you read the data into `R`, do you use `check.names = FALSE` otherwise it will append 'X' at the beginning of dataes.  Here, we don't need any rows as this is specific issue with ordering the column names

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187495/discussion-between-akrun-and-musthedataguy).